# MapKit, draw line with a finger and get coordinates

Tags: swift, xcode

Using MapKit, is it possible to draw a line with a finger and get the coordinates, e.g. every 5 meters? Thanks for help!

Comment: So, you would stop the map from scrolling before that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the map's panning and zooming features and intercept the touches yourself. You could then convert the coordinates of the touch events to real world coordinates with:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452503-convertpoint